# Class-like closures in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to do something like this in Ruby:

```
class A
  def b(c)
    Class.new do
      def d
        c
      end
    end
  end
end

class B < A.b('whoa'); end

#
# What I want:
#
B.new.d # => 'whoa'

#
# What I get:
#
# NameError: undefined local variable or method `d' for B:0xfdfyadayada
```

Is there any way to do this?

The context is I'm trying to get some code reuse by constructing classes that are mostly similar except for some minor config.

I'm looking for an API similar to Sequel::Model where you can do something like:

```
class Order < Sequel::Model(:order)
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the error you are getting? running the same exact code, I get `undefined method 'b' for A:Class (NoMethodError)` which is the expected behaviour given that `A` doesn't have a class method `b`. Are you sure it's `def b` and not `deb self.b`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contents of a method definition using the `def` keyword are not lexically scoped the way blocks are. In other words you can’t do something like this:

```
foo = 7
def bar
  # Code here inside the method definition can't
  # "see" foo, so this doesn't work.
  foo
end
```

However you *can* use the [`define_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Module.html#method-i-define_method) method to dynamically define a method using a block, and the block *will* be able to refer to local variables in its outer scope. So in your case you could do this (I’ve also changed `def b` to `def self.b`, which I think is what you meant):

```
class A
  def self.b(c)
    Class.new do
      define_method(:d) do # N.B. the d here is a symbol
        c
      end
    end
  end
end
class B < A.b('whoa'); end
B.new.d # => 'whoa'
```

This would also work if you created other classes:

```
class C < A.b('dude'); end
C.new.d # => 'dude'

# B still works
B.new.d # => 'whoa'
```

Comment: I like this answer. Dude what the hell stop knowing too much.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `b` is a class method (i.e `def self.b` instead of `def b`), you could store `c` in a class variable.

```
class A
  def self.b(c)
    Class.new do
      @@c = c

      def d
        @@c
      end
    end
  end
end

class B < A.b('whoa'); end

puts B.new.d # => whoa
```

There could be a better solution, I haven't looked at the source code of Sequel. This is just the first thing that came to my mind.